# How can I join started Actor?

Tags: scala

After starting an actor

```
val a = actor {
  loop {
    react {
      case "end" => exit
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

And sending "end" message to it

```
a ! "end"
```

I want to make sure the thread is finished.
How can it be joined?

Comment: I think [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4304506/298389) will answer on your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know an actor can't be joined explicitly as in the Java-way. The concept is to introduce event-based programming, so it should only react on events. 
You can trap the exit however and link your initial actor (A) to the ending actor (B) via `link`. That way the initial actor A receives an event when B ends. If you don't get any event you know the actor hasn't terminated. See the thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304602/999865

If you don't care about resources and *knows* that the thread will terminate you can also make the actor inherit from `DaemonActor`. Daemon actors doesn't block any system resources.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that the "actor-way" of doing what you want is actually have your actor reply with a message "Done" to the requester, so it can take action. That way it is all still asynchronous event handling