# Scala folding using Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I implemented in Java what I called a "foldable queue", i.e., a LinkedBlockingQueue used by an ExecutorService. The idea is that each task as a unique id that if is in the queue while another task is submitted via that same id, it is not added to the queue. The Java code looks like this:

```
public final class FoldablePricingQueue extends LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> {
    @Override
    public boolean offer(final Runnable runnable) {
        if (contains(runnable)) {
            return true; // rejected, but true not to throw an exception
        } else {
            return super.offer(runnable);
        }
    }
}
```

Threads have to be pre-started but this is a minor detail. I have an Abstract class that implements Runnable that takes a unique id... this is the one passed in

I would like to implement the same logic using Scala and Akka (Actors).
I would need to have access to the mailbox, and I think I would need to override the ! method and check the mailbox for the event.. has anyone done this before?

Comment: Reading this as I just posted this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721337/best-method-to-peek-into-a-scala-actors-mailbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *exactly* how the Akka mailbox works. The Akka mailbox can only exist once in the task-queue.

Look at:

https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/dispatch/Dispatcher.scala#L143

https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/dispatch/Dispatcher.scala#L198

Very cheaply implemented using an atomic boolean, so no need to traverse the queue.

Also, by the way, your Queue in Java is broken since it doesn't override put, add or offer(E, long, TimeUnit).

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstood my question. I am not asking about the number of instances of MB per Q, but more about accepting tasks into a MB if they are already in the MB

Comment: Simplest is probably just creating your own mailbox implementation for your dispatcher. Look at how It's done and just override the enqueue method

Comment: Override the createMailbox method of your dispatcher to return a mailbox that does deduplication, check the source for Akka 1.2) for ExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher.scala which shows how createMailbox is overridden to create a custom type of mailbox.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could do that with two actors. A `facade` one and a `worker` one. Clients send jobs to `facade`. `Facade` forwards then to `worker`, and remember them in its internal state, a Set `queuedJobs`. When it receives a job that is `queued`, it just discard it. Each time the `worker` starts processing a job (or completes it, whichever suits you), it sends a `StartingOn`(job) message to facade, which removes it from queuedJobs.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do this - but looking at the Java version which is very simple, I was expected even a simpler way to do this using Akka. May be the right question to add is: do I have access to the mail box via a well defined API?

Comment: @JTS: I don't think you can. BTW, *didierd* solution is very easy and I'm sure that the implemented code will not be longer that the Java solution you have shown. To ease the task, you can for example use `forward` which allows easy forwarding by preserving the sender.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/akka-user/browse_thread/thread/67077cad1b2bc4b2/1ff72599f5843e25?lnk=gst&q=mailbox#1ff72599f5843e25

Answer (score 1):

The proposed design doesn't make sense. The closest thing to a `Runnable` would be an `Actor`. Sure, you can keep them in a list, and not add them if they are already there. Such lists are kept by [routing actors](http://akka.io/api/akka/1.2/#akka.routing.package), which can be created from ready parts provided by Akka, or from a basic actor using the `forward` method.

You can't look into another actor's mailbox, and overriding `!` makes no sense. What you do is you send all your messages to a routing actor, and that routing actor forwards them to a proper destination.

Naturally, since it *receives* these messages, it can do any logic at that point.

Comment: I agree. Looks like the best option. Will give it a go.